# I want to ask a too broad question and answer it with a tutorial I wrote myself. What will the be the community's reaction?

Tags: discussion, questions, self-answer

We were asked to set up a LAMP server on an unused desktop PC a week ago. I am a complete newbie regarding this matter. The only experience I had was that I was slightly familiar with vi and the terminal. So I researched on how to do this task and we were successful in setting up the LAMP server.

I then wrote a simple tutorial on how to setup a LAMP server from scratch and I would like to post it here in a [Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) style with a title that goes like this:

```
How do I set up a LAMP server from scratch using CentOS 6.7?
```

Then I would provide the tutorial I wrote as an answer.

I am new to the SuperUser community, but I'm not exactly new to the StackExchange network. I would like to ask the community's reaction. If I post this. Will it get downvoted and closed?

To express the reasons why I want to do this:

- it will be easier to look for it if I need it later
- so that others will see what I have done, and they can comment the things that I might have done wrong
- someone else might have the same problem(my question is installing LAMP from scratch)

Also, should I mark it as community wiki?

---

Edit: I posted the question [here](https://superuser.com/q/993316/406714).

Comment: Sure, post it. Seems to be on-topic for Super User. And as for community wiki, that's up to you.

Comment: @Insane thanks for the response. It's not that I'm not respecting your opinion but I still want to wait for what others will say.

Comment: It goes in the same category as [this](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit) question, I think. But yeah, do what you want.

Comment: If that is the case then it is on topic.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the answer. With 7 upvotes, and from your comments, I think it would be okay to post this question. I'll just let the community sort it out.

Comment: "How do I set up a LAMP server from scratch using CentOS 6.7?" can be separated on "setting up apache, mysql, php/perl". And I really don´t thing it should be in a single post dealing with the entire process, instead several with each step explained (there are many ways to put php and apache together, from 2.0, 2.2 and 2.4, for example).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We like canonical and complete answers and I personally don't see any reason for it to be classed as off topic as such.

Typically a question and answer should be short and to the point, but a canonical answer detailing how to do something properly and succinctly is always appreciated.

One thing to keep in mind though is whether or not you need to update it when components get updated and the process changes.

Comment: With regards to updating the process when components are update.  You can prevent yourself from having to come back to the question and answer by limiting the scope of the question to specific version(s).  By doing that you basically indicate to reviewer(s) that any new answers should be limited to those version(s) also.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I feel assured to have an answer from a moderator. As per updating the answer, I am considering following Ramhound's advice here because the one that asked us to set up the server specified the versions of CentOS, Apache, MySQL and PHP in their request. Anyways, there is no need to worry as I am very active on  SO and I continually improve my posts so if something changes I'll visit this site too. :)

Comment: On another note, could I ask to make the question a community wiki too? I would like to 'dissociate' from the question and give it to the community. But please use your best judgment. If you think it is okay as it is, then it is okay for me too. Just a very very minor request from me.